# PHP - Is there a portable version of PHPUnit?

Tags: php, phpunit

Is there a portable version of PHPUnit that I can bundle with my web app? I want to be able to use phpunit on any server while avoiding the issues of using PEAR (version conflicts, breaking other hosted apps, etc.).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/7324017/632951

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Portable phpunit (taken from https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit "Using PHPUnit From a Git Checkout" )

For phpunit 3.5:

```
git clone git://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit.git
git clone git://github.com/sebastianbergmann/dbunit.git
git clone git://github.com/sebastianbergmann/php-file-iterator.git
git clone git://github.com/sebastianbergmann/php-text-template.git
git clone git://github.com/sebastianbergmann/php-code-coverage.git
git clone git://github.com/sebastianbergmann/php-token-stream.git
git clone git://github.com/sebastianbergmann/php-timer.git
git clone git://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit-mock-objects.git
git clone git://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit-selenium.git

cd phpunit && git checkout 3.5 && cd ..
cd dbunit && git checkout 1.0 && cd ..
cd php-file-iterator && git checkout 1.2 && cd ..
cd php-code-coverage && git checkout 1.0 && cd ..
cd php-token-stream && git checkout 1.0 && cd ..
cd phpunit-mock-objects && git checkout 1.0 && cd ..
cd phpunit-selenium && git checkout 1.0 && cd ..
```

and then put every single of those folders into your include path.

It will not work if you leave out any one of those packages.

If you don't want to always have them in the include path here is a phpunit.sh executable

#### phpunit.sh

```
x='./checkoutDir/';

php -d include_path=".:$x/phpunit/:$x/dbunit/:$x/php-code-coverage/:$x/php-file-iterator/:$x/php-text-template/:$x/php-timer/:$x/php-token-stream/:$x/phpunit-mock-objects/:$x/phpunit-selenium/:$x/phpunit-story/:/usr/share/php/"  $x/phpunit/phpunit.php $*
```

Answer (score 3):

The [answer by edorian was spot on](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4802697/208809) at the time it was written (and probably still is useful today). However, nowadays there is some more convenient options at your disposal.

In addition to [fixing to a specific PhpUnit via Composer](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/phpunit-book.html#installation.composer), you can also download PHPUnit as a Phar and use that.

Quoting https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit

> We distribute a PHP Archive (PHAR) that has all required (as well as some optional) dependencies of PHPUnit bundled in a single file:

```
wget https://phar.phpunit.de/phpunit.phar
chmod +x phpunit.phar
mv phpunit.phar /usr/local/bin/phpunit
```

Answer (score 2):

The answer from edorian missed the Symfony/Yaml package. Moreover, Symfony/Finder seemed to be needed, although not mentioned in PHPUnit's readme file.

Regarding to PEAR dependency, it's only the PHPUnit's selftest that tends to need it. At least I have managed to run the whole test suite of Zend Framework 2 without problems. And I hadn't PEAR installed.

Here's the installer for PHPUnit Git checkout that I have made https://github.com/kblomqvist/gitinstall-phpunit.