# How can I make a portable PHPUnit?

Tags: php, continuous-integration, dependencies, phpunit, pear

I’m trying to do some TDD on PHP. I’m writing tests on PHPunit. So far so good.
The problem is that I would like to have PHPUnit under version control, so we don’t have to install it in each coder machine and in the CI server. This may be valid for any other dependency.

What I did was to install PHPUnit via PEAR and just copy the installed files to my project library folder. Is this correct, or is there a better way to do it??

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This question's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4801183/php-is-there-a-portable-version-of-phpunit) accepted answer would be a perfect solution for you especially if you are using GIT, if you are using something else, it shouldn't be too hard to modify....

Rkulla's answer is good except quite a few comments for the blog post does state that Sebastian does not address the dependency issue for the required modules

Comment: doing the checkout once and then storing the stuff in your own version control can also work out quite nicely (along with the needed php.ini that changes all the include paths)

Comment: Thanks for the help. I needed to include the path to every library. It works now in every machine, including the continuous integration server ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Just check, that there are no any hardcoded pathes. I believe, it's so. So if all pathes are realtive, then it's ok.

Each developer can then checkout it and setup start script by themself.

Answer (score 0):

See http://sebastian-bergmann.de/archives/876-PHPUnit-Development-Moved-to-GitHub.html. It talks about using svn:externals and the like.