# PHPUNIT without installation

Tags: php, installation, webserver, phpunit

I'm sorry if the question is stupid for some reason. I'm not a phpunit expert and what I'm asking could sound ridiculous.

Is it possible to use phpunit without installation? Just "include" the libraries without installing anything on the server?

I'm asking this because at my workplace nobody wants to try some unit testing or TDDing but I'm pretty sure that I can do a better work when I program with the help of the tests and besides I want to show my coworkers that "it works" after the fact, not just by talking*.

Thanks for your help

*Talking already happened and the answer is always something like "We have too much work to do to consider these fancy things". Life seems to be too short to do a good job.

Comment: there are no stupid questions, only stupid people.

Comment: There *are* stupid questions. I use up all my votes every day downvoting cthem. However, this is not one of them!

Comment: If you find yourself needing to prove TDD or unit testing works: Get a new job. Sounds like a horrible atmosphere full of b graders. No offense, I'm sure they're "really cool people".

Comment: Testing is not fancy, but a developers daily work. Because it is, you should automate tests. PHPUnit is the tool to go in the PHP world to  automate your unit-tests quite fast.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP - Is there a portable version of PHPUnit?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4801183/php-is-there-a-portable-version-of-phpunit)

Comment: *(related)* [Can I package PHPUnit as a phar?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7324017/can-i-package-phpunit-as-a-phar/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [readme on PHPUnit's github repository](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/) has instructions for this. Scroll down to *Using PHPUnit From a Git Checkout* for a list of commands you can copy-n-paste into your shell.

One thing to make clear to your coworkers is that while writing tests *in addition to* your regular code may seem like more work up front, well-written tests will save you time over the long run as you fix bugs and add features. They also give you the confidence to make more drastic changes as necessary whereas you might normally consider rewriting the project from scratch.