# How to bundle PHPUnit with my code?

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit

I would like to:

- Run tests with PHPUnit regardless of my environment (and if PHPUnit or PEAR is installed or not)
- Show test results on screen if possible

How can I do this? I tried downloading the code [here](http://pear.phpunit.de/) and including `Autoload.php` but it still have some dependencies. Maybe there's some better approach for this than trying to bundle it with my code...?

Answer (score 2):

To include PHPUnit in your projects source files I'd suggest following the guide:

[**`Using PHPUnit From a Git Checkout`**](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md) from the PHPUnit Contributung section.

It tells you about all the packages you need to install and shows you show to build a runner/wrapper script for the phpunit executable.

```
#!/bin/bash
php -d include_path='.:../phpunit/:../dbunit/:../php-code-coverage/:../php-file-iterator/:../php-invoker/:../php-text-template/:../php-timer:../php-token-stream:../phpunit-mock-objects/:../phpunit-selenium/:../phpunit-story/:/usr/local/lib/php' ../phpunit/phpunit.php $*
```

You can adapt the path to your need or if you want to wrap it in another script you can also use phpunit somewhat programmatically by

```
require '/path/to/phpunit/PHPUnit/Autoload.php';
PHPUnit_TextUI_Command::main();
```

This assumes that you ether have a `phpunit.xml.dist` file or that you use the proper cli parameters when calling your wrapper script.

---

You can also use the pear packages and unpack all the stable versions instead of working from the git checkout to save some disk and repo space. The wrapper script and all the include path work is the same :)

---

Related SO questions:

[PHP - Is there a portable version of PHPUnit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4801183/php-is-there-a-portable-version-of-phpunit)

[PHPUNIT without installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7628573/phpunit-without-installation)

Answer (score 1):

The dependencies will be dependent on what add-ons you're using, PHPUnit by itself should be self contained.  Since there's no particularly consistent package management solution for PHP (and you've eliminated the most viable options aside from wheel reinvention), your best bet would be to include the files in the source tree *separate from the application code*.  Creating a sibling directory from whatever your APPLICATION_ROOT or similar would be that is named "test" and that has a "lib" or similar directory full of PHPUnit and any dependencies you need for it would likely be a good plan.  There should be no overlapping and a one way dependency from the test dir to the main application source.

I'm assuming you're looking for a healthcheck automated test page, so you could create the single page that includes what is needed from that test directory.  Ideally if you have the web directory which exposes your static resources you could have the PHP file that is in charge of loading the Front Controller for your application by including the application folder from outside of the document root, and then a second file that loads the test suite.  That would allow your application directory to remain focused on the application code itself, the test directory to house your testing code, and then the 2 small include files which are in charge of loading the codebases (with any kind of shared constant definitions, etc. also extracted and kept DRY).

Comment: I must be including the library in the wrong way then, but I saw no mention on how to do this on the official docs. And about the "healthceck automated test page", it has to be inside the project folder, so it can be in the production server when I deploy. I don't know how to display the tests on screen as the documentation only seems to talk about the command line.

Comment: Displaying results should be in the report generation section of the docs (you could also just publish the reports under document root).  The tests should be inside of the deployed folder if you go that route, but it should be a sibling of the application code directory not underneath it.  There should be a means to dispatch to the 2 different folders without having to mix the code.  For execution I'd start with the command line method (called through PHP) since that is how the tests would be run manually or using a build tool, and then look at swapping in API calls later.

Comment: but how to correctly include the lib from my code? and how to run the tests from php itself (without the command line)?

Comment: Include using require or autoloader as needed like any other file.  PHP is pretty indifferent as to where the code is coming from.  Run using something like: http://www.phpunit.de/manual/3.0/en/api.html#api.testsuite.examples.TestSuite-example.php

Answer (score 1):

There is a consistent package management solution for PHP - http://getComposer.org. It also now has a means to install PHPunit in the usual composer style, http://packagist.org/packages/phpunit/phpunit

With the software installed, it will put the phpunit command line script into the local 'bin/' directory, so you can call it, though you will likely want to have a shell script that also sets the configuration file it will use.

The usual setup is a tests/ subdirectory with the hierarchy of PHPunit-extending classes that run the actual tests.

Comment: ..neither is composer portable.