# Is it possible to install PHPUnit without pear?

Tags: phpunit

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP - Is there a portable version of PHPUnit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4801183/php-is-there-a-portable-version-of-phpunit)

On a Red Hat Linux machine, without root privileges, so can not use pear.

Manual download leads to https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/, but this seems a windows version since the executable is a phpunit.bat.

Is there a way to install PHPUnit on Linux without PEAR?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Further down on the same page, it says how to install PHPUnit from a git checkout:

[PHPUnit from a git checkout](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/#using-phpunit-from-a-git-checkout)

Answer (score 3):

I have made an installer for this: https://github.com/kblomqvist/gitinstall-phpunit

Comment: Thx. Is it possible to do make without root privileges?

Comment: Of course. The installation happens locally. If you follow the README instructions, then ~/local/phpunit will be your installation directory. Furthermore, if you like to install different version, edit fetch.php.